# Sort files with Date instance with enough precision(nanosecond) in node.js

Tags: node.js, date, precision

I would like to get nano second precision (if needed) for [`Date` instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to sort these ten numbers which I created with this bash file

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p count
touch count/1
touch count/2
touch count/3
touch count/4
touch count/5
touch count/6
touch count/7
touch count/8
touch count/9
touch count/10
```

I have the following script and I would like to sort them like below:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

But I get:

```
[ '/home/kaartje2go/node/delete-all-but-x-files/count',
  '/home/kaartje2go/node/delete-all-but-x-files/count/9',
  '/home/kaartje2go/node/delete-all-but-x-files/count/10',
  '/home/kaartje2go/node/delete-all-but-x-files/count/2',
  '/home/kaartje2go/node/delete-all-but-x-files/count/3',
  '/home/kaartje2go/node/delete-all-but-x-files/count/5',
  '/home/kaartje2go/node/delete-all-but-x-files/count/6',
  '/home/kaartje2go/node/delete-all-but-x-files/count/7',
  '/home/kaartje2go/node/delete-all-but-x-files/count/8',
  '/home/kaartje2go/node/delete-all-but-x-files/count/4',
  '/home/kaartje2go/node/delete-all-but-x-files/count/1' ]
```

I used the following script:

```
'use strict'

const fs = require('fs-extra')
const items = [] // files, directories, symlinks, etc
fs.walk('./count')
  .on('data', function (item) {
    items.push(item)
  })
  .on('end', function () {
    const mtimes =  items.sort((a,b) => b.stats.mtime - a.stats.mtime);
    console.log(mtimes.map(mtime => mtime.path));
 });
```

When I sort for example via nautilus(Ubuntu) it works correctly:

[image]

I assume this should be possible native(JS only), but please correct me if wrong.

Comment: I think the `Date` object is only up till a precision of milliseconds. :(

Comment: I think so two so we can not sort with this kind o precision I guess?

Comment: Not sure yet I can do some research on this later. I think meanwhile if we can't work out a solution, as a workaround u can consider using `shelljs` to do a `ls` by last modified, then capture the output and parse it to whatever format u like. I think it should work too. If u like I can try write a sample code when I get home later.